# How to check if the user is visiting the page for the first time

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-models

In general how do we know if user is visiting the page for the first time? Technically, do we store the number of visits to each page in the Model(I am using django) or is there some other pattern that I could follow to ease up the operation.

I m just looking for a design for implementing this.

Comment: use the User model field date_joined

Comment: How is the joining date of user related to page visits?

Comment: date joined stores date and time the first time user register and last login store the recent login date and time of the user. If you can imagine you can create a logic (condition) there for your problem. But if you can't, never mind.

Comment: @catherine thanks a lot for the info I would love to try it out. But I m guessing there are better solutions available if I m touching the Model.

Comment: nah, you can make if and else statement in your view

Comment: Are you looking for anonymous users, or signed-up users? Do you just want the first time they view any page, or the first time they view everypage?

Comment: signed-up user and first-time they visit any page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will have to create your own mechanism for this.

I would make a model storing first visits for every url and user called e.g `FirstVisit`. Then if a user requests a page in a view you can search if there is an entry in `FirstVisit` for current user and url and find out if it's his first time or not. After that, if he hasn't visited yet, you store the entry to the `FirstVisit` model, because he is just going to get the content of the page.

I will try and write the code:

```
#models.py

class FirstVisit(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')


#views.py

def my_view(request):
   if not FisrtVisit.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, url=request.path).exists():
      #he visits for the first time
      #your code...
      FisrtVisit(user=request.user, url=request.path).save()
```

You can create a decorator and put in there this functionality. Then add the decorator to any view you want to store this information and from the decorator pass a flag argument to the view determining if user is there for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Following @davekr suggestion, I would create a model like FirstVisit with some attributes like ip-address, time registered and instante it on the get method (that is tied to the root url) with some validation if the user is valid or authenticated.

PS: Check this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/) django docs to indentify the request attributes that could be of your interest to construct the FirstVisit.