# Django - Show message in template if this user has not been on the site before

Tags: python, django

I was wondering how might I show a new user a message such as 'First time here?' in a Django template using conditionals?

e.g.

```
{% if this_website_has_not_been_accessed_by_user %}
<h3>First time here?</h3>
<h5>Follow these steps...</h5>
{% endif %}
```

What might be the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: If a user uses your site for the first time? Or only if he accesses that specific page for the first time?

Comment: If it concerns a specific page: Are there many such pages where you want to know if the user is accessing them for the first time?

Comment: @Ralf Use the site for the first time; apologies I shall edit my Q to be clearer on that

Comment: did you get to solve your problem?

Comment: @Ralf Not fully no hahah, though your solution was good I was looking for something where the user is completely new (i.e. has not made an account yet and is visiting the home oage for the first time)

Comment: In that case you could use a flag in the session: if a user is not logged in, then show the message until he clicks a `dismiss` button (which you store in the session).

Comment: @Ralf That sounds like a great idea! I'm not too familiar with sessions in Django, how might that work in code? If you add it to your answer then I'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only want to show that banner at the top of the page for logged in users (those that have a `User` instance in the current request), you could create a Model (or, if you have your own user profile model, add a field to it) to save that.

```
class Access(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    has_been_here_before = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In your view you would have to check that Model to see if the user is registered there and has the flag set.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126536/how-to-differentiate-the-first-time-registered-and-regular-logged-in-user-in-dja) for detecting first login.

See also [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699947/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-visiting-the-page-for-the-first-time) for detecting a visit to each individual page or view.

---

EDIT: according to your comments you want to show the welcome banner to anonymous users (not logged in) if they visit for the first time.

You could achieve that using [djangos session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/). You can use [`request.session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) just like a simple dict.

In your home page view (or through a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) so it affects all pages not just the home page) you could check if a user has already dismissed the welcome banner or not.

```
def my_home_view(request):
    ...
    # as default 'show_welcome_banner' will be True
    context['show_welcome_banner'] = request.session.get('show_welcome_banner', True)
    ...
```

Then, in your template use:

```
{% if show_welcome_banner %}
    <h3>First time here?</h3>
    <h5>Follow these steps...</h5>
{% endif %}
```

Your banner could have a 'dismiss' button that posts a hidden to a different url (maybe even through ajax). This url would alter the users session info:

```
def dismiss_welcome_banner(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['show_welcome_banner'] = False
    ...
```

Notes:

1. if a user access the site through incognito mode (the session cockie gets deleted when he closes the browser) he will need to click the dismiss button every time he opens the incognito browser.
2. You could additionally check that loggen in users do not get to see that banner, depending of how you prefer it.

Comment: There's no need to create a dedicated `has_been_here_before` field, because you can just check if [`User.last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) is empty.